# Spectrum and resolvent of an operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, adjoint-operators

So for the operator $A:l_2(\Bbb C)\to l_2(\Bbb C)$ defined as:

$$A(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_m,x_{m+1},x_{m+2},\cdots) = (x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_m,0,0,\cdots)$$

We can find the adjoint operator $A^*$ by looking at:

$$\langle Ax,y\rangle = \sum_{i=1}^m x_i\overline{y}_i = \sum_{i=1}^\infty x_i A^*(\overline{y})_i$$

$\implies A^*(\overline{y})_i = (\overline y_1, \overline  y_2,\cdots,\overline y_m,0,\cdots)$

So then:
$$\langle Ax,y\rangle = \sum_{i=1}^m x_i\overline{y}_i = \sum_{i=1}^\infty x_i A^*(\overline{y})_i = \sum_{i=1}^m x_i\overline y_i=\langle x,A^*y\rangle$$

Is that correct?

Now how do I find the spectrum of $A$ and the resolvent of $A$?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. Did you try to apply the definition of spectrum and resolvent?

Comment: I am using Kreyszig and I am having trouble understanding the definitions @gerw I have that $R_\lambda = (A- \lambda I)^{-1}$ is the resolvent operator, and I think the spectrum is the points in which that function exists, so I can't work with that until I understand $R_\lambda$

Comment: The spectrum consists of all points $\lambda$ for which $A-\lambda\,I$ **fails** to be boundedly invertible. So I would suggest the following: Take some $\lambda$ (maybe $0$, or $1$ or $2$) and try to "understand" $A - \lambda \, I$ to get a feeling, what conditions are needed for its invertibility.

Comment: @gerw Can I ask you one dumb question before I dig into it? What is $I$ in this case? Surely $I$ in the finite dimensional case is the identity matrix, but  what about here?

Comment: In the finite-dimensional case, $I$ is the matrix that, when operated on a vector, leaves the vector unchanged. It's the same for the infinite-dimensional case. i.e.  $I:l_2(\mathbb{C})\to l_2(\mathbb{C})$ is the operator such that $Ix=x$ for all $x\in l_2(\mathbb{C})$.

Answer (score 1):

The operator $A$ is the orthgonal projection onto the span of $\{ e_1,e_2,\cdots,e_m\}$, where $e_j$ is the j-th standard basis element of $\ell^2$. So $A^2=A=A^{\star}$. To invert $A-\lambda I$, the inversion can be done separately on the range of $A$ and on the null space of $A$ because these are invariant under $A$ and mutually orthogonal, with $\ell^2=\mathcal{N}(A)\oplus\mathcal{R}(A)$. On $\mathcal{N}(A)$, $(A-\lambda I)$ is $-\lambda I$. On $\mathcal{R}(A)$, $(A-\lambda I)$ is $(1-\lambda)I$. So, the inverse is
$$
              (A-\lambda I)^{-1} = -\frac{1}{\lambda}(I-A)+\frac{1}{1-\lambda}A.
$$
You can directly verify that the above holds for $\lambda\notin\{0,1\}$; this requires knowing only that $A^2=A$. That is, you can verify that
$$
       \left[-\frac{1}{\lambda}(I-A)+\frac{1}{1-\lambda}A\right](A-\lambda I)=I,\\
       (A-\lambda I)\left[-\frac{1}{\lambda}(I-A)+\frac{1}{1-\lambda}A\right]=I.
$$
And you can verify that $A-\lambda I$ is not invertible for $\lambda=0$ or $\lambda=1$ because $\mathcal{N}(A)\ne \{0\}$ and $\mathcal{N}(A-I)\ne \{0\}$. So the spectrum of $A$ is $\sigma(A)=\{0,1\}$. This is true of any non-trivial projection.